# In shinydashboard, the white box is getting clipped in the top right and bottom right parts

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am creating a simple sinydashboard plot in a box. For some reason, the white box in which the plot is set is getting clipped on the top right and bottom right part. This happens when I set the box width to more than 500.

Here is my code :

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinydashboard)

#ui object 
ui <- fluidPage(
   dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(width = 0),
      dashboardBody(
         fluidRow(
            column(width = 12, 
                box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 400, width = 700)) 
            )
         )
      )
   )
)

#server object 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data = diamonds) +
         geom_line(aes(x = depth, y = price)) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that widths and heights of graphs take a bit of tweaking. For your example I would probably use:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(width = 0),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 400), width = 12) 
      )
    )
  )
)
```

If you then want to shorten the width of the chart, just tweak the box width variable. 12 is full window width, 6 will be half, etc.

Comment: Thanks very much, olorcain. It worked. Though it would be good to know why it works. In my code, I thought I was setting the column width to full (12) and then in the box function, setting the width to what the plot width should be.

Comment: Glad it helped. I think that by explicitly specifying the plot width of 700px, you were overriding the flexible bootstrap column widths used by the shiny framework. So the box was responding to the size of the window, but the chart was staying a static size. If you rerun your original code and change the window size on your app you may see what I mean.